# On orientation change (screen rotate) EditText all show the same value because they share the same id

Tags: android

I have the following XML definition that I programmatically instantiate many times, depending on the number of items from a database. Each instance is a `TableRow` that is later added to a `TableLayout`.  The `TableLayout` is defined elsewhere (in the activity XML definition).

**group_editblinds.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/group_editblindschedule"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:text="Round" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/editText2"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="2"
      android:hint="Small"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:text="0" />

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/name"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:ems="2"
      android:hint="Big"
      android:inputType="number"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
      android:paddingRight="6dip"
      android:text="0" >
    </EditText>

    <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</TableRow>
```

I have read from other answers that because I have instantiated the same view many times, each view contains the same Id.

My activity is pretty simple. The only extra-piece is that it has a user-defined object, `BlindSchedule`, that is used to populate the `EditView`s. This must be retained on orientation change. You can think of this activity as a database create/update depending on how we got to the activity.

```
public class EditBlindScheduleActivity extends Activity {

  private TableLayout table;
  private BlindSchedule bs;
  private EditText name;

  boolean creating;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_blind_schedule);

    if (savedInstanceState == null)
    {
      bs = (BlindSchedule) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("blindSchedule");
    }

    table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.editblindtable);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);

    if (bs == null) {
      creating = true;
    } else {
      creating = false;
    }

    if (creating) 
    {
      setTitle("Create Blind Schedule");

      for(int i = 1; i < 26; ++i)
      {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.group_editblindschedule, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
        tv.setText("" + i);
        table.addView(row);
      }
    } 
    else 
    {
      setTitle("Edit Blind Schedule");

      name.setText(bs.getName());

      int i = 1;
      for (BlindLevel level : bs.getBlindLevels())
      {
        TableRow row = (TableRow) View.inflate(this, R.layout.group_editblindschedule, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) row.getChildAt(0);
        tv.setText("" + i);
        EditText et = (EditText) row.getChildAt(1);
        et.setText("" + level.getSmallBlind());
        et = (EditText) row.getChildAt(2);
        et.setText("" + level.getBigBlind());
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) row.getChildAt(3);
        cb.setChecked(true);
        table.addView(row);
        ++i;
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
      bs = (BlindSchedule) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("blindSchedule");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if (bs != null) {
      outState.putSerializable("blindSchedule", bs);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
}
```

When I get to the activity to edit a BlindSchedule, the values look something like:

```
1 2
2 4 
4 8
16 32
100 200
```

When I rotate the screen, I get:

```
100 200
100 200
100 200
100 200
100 200
```

Again, I believe this is because all my views have the same Id due to the fact that the same XML resource was instantiated multiple times.  What is the correct way to fix this annoyance?

Comment: if the same view item is instantiated many times why don't you use ListView?

Comment: Well, that's probably a good point... and maybe the solution (if I port my code to use ListView). I chose not to use ListView probably because I don't have a great understanding of what its used for.

Comment: yeah I noticed that :) acctually TableLayout should be used only if your data is constant and you know how many roes are there right from binging, otherwise in your case you should use ListView with custom item and adapter

Comment: add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" under activity tag in manifest

Comment: I converted my code to a `ListView` and came to the conclusion that it's "The Wrong Way to Do It". Having `EditText` fields inside a `ListView` is a very bad thing. There is no perfect solution that allows the `EditText` to be focusable. You can search StackOverflow for "EditText ListView focus" and see the myriad of problems and potential solutions -- each solution with certain drawbacks in certain cases. I think I will need to go back to my original implementation, and I'm crossing my fingers that TmKVU's answer will work for me.

Comment: In addition, the nested `EditText`s do not retain their state on orientation change if they belong to a `ListView`. In general, it appears Android can't properly reference these views and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Vilen Melkumyan that you should use a `ListView`. `ListView` and `Adapter` can be intimidating at first, but they will prove to be powerful tools when you learn to use them.

To answer your question, if you want to stick with the `TableLayout`, you can add the following to your activity in the  `AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```

This will prevent the `Activity`to be reloaded after the orientation state changes.

Comment: @mindandsky That is possible. With a custom adapter (extending BaseAdapter class) you can use any kind of View you want for your List rows, including nested Views. Here is [tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/) to get you started

Comment: If you see my other comment, you'll see that I listed some problems with embedding `EditText` inside `ListView`. Maybe a heads up for you so you don't end up going down the path I did! :D

Comment: Worked for me! But people are recommending fragments. Are there any disadvantages of this approach over fragments? Or this can be considered as a standard way?

Comment: @MangeshGhotage This question and answer are not regarding fragments.  The `ListView` with `Adapter` approach is still the best way to go when working with lists. I suggest you read about fragments in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)