# Unexpected EditText reuse

Tags: android

Implementing a table-like UI I met a really strange behaviour. After rotating the screen all rows contain the same edit text field

Here is my code:

Main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        addRow(inflater, layout, "A", 0);
        addRow(inflater, layout, "B", 1);
        addRow(inflater, layout, "C", 2);
    }

    private void addRow(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup layout, String title, int value) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);
        Row row = (Row) view;
        row.setTitle(title);
        row.setValue(value);
        layout.addView(row);
    }
}
```

Main activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="wrap_content"
    a:layout_gravity="center"
    a:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        a:id="@+id/table_layout"
        a:orientation="vertical"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Table row:

```
public class Row extends LinearLayout {

    public Row(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public Row(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        final TextView titleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        titleView.setText(title);
    }

    public void setValue(int i) {
        final TextView valueEdit = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
        valueEdit.setText("" + i);
    }
}
```

Table row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.anagaf.freqhelper.Row
    xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="match_parent"
    a:layout_height="match_parent"
    a:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        a:id="@+id/title"
        style="@style/RangeTitle"
        a:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/gap"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <EditText
        a:id="@+id/value"
        style="@style/ChannelEdit"/>

</com.anagaf.freqhelper.Row>
```

After the app starts the table looks ok:

```
A 0 
B 1
C 2
```

If I change the screen orientation to landscape the table changes to:

```
A 2
B 2
C 2
```

It looks like the EditText from the last row is re-used for all rows.

If I replace value EditText with TextView - everything is ok

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23968524/4385913) , he had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating the ViewGroup `inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null, false);` as a View. Instead, inflate it as a `ViewGroup` then use `yourviewgroup.findById(R.id.someview)` to get each element you want to fill.

Even better would be to create a new layout in code, then inflate your 'template' layout and instantiate each element from there. Then you use the created layout to display the elements you just instantiated.

This way you can inflate the layout only once and pass it as a variable to each row, return a new layout and put it in the activity's layout.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your idea. Could you please provide some code?

Comment: Can you specify which part is not clear so I can take that into account?